# How to get all repositories of a specific GitHub user

Tags: python

How to get all repositories (`> 100`) of a specific [GitHub](http://www.github.com) user using a simple HTTP library like [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) or [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).

Comment: Why don't use github API?

Comment: Do you have any specific problems you've encountered while trying?

Comment: Sorry. I just wanted to document my solution and forgot to click the corresponding button. Not sure why you're downvoting now. This way is not yet documented here. I'll move the solution to my blog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get more than `100` repositories from GitHub it's necessary to follow the links inside the [link header](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#link-headers).

```
import requests

def get_repositories(url):
    result = []
    r = requests.get(url=url)
    if 'next' in r.links :
        result += get_repositories(r.links['next']['url'])

    for repository in r.json():
        result.append(repository.get('name'))

    return result

url = "https://api.github.com/users/stackforge/repos"
print get_repositories(url)
```